# Blank screen after granting permission

Tags: android

I am getting a blank screen after granting permission.

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
            Log.d("permission","permission");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);

        }

}



 public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
Log.d("requestCode",String.valueOf(requestCode));
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Do your work.
                   // finish();
                    //startActivity(getIntent());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we cannot proceed further", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

I get the dialog asking for camera and location permission. After allowing I get a blank screen and the phone hangs.

I am getting "Debugger is no longer active" and nothing else. I am getting the allow permission dialog but I am not getting the permission tag nor is my OnRequestPermissionsResult() called.

Can please someone help me with this?

Comment: What your LogCat say? I assume that you can see "permission" tag after checking `hasPermissions()`, but is `requestCode` is 1 as expected?
Do you do this checking in ActivityMAin.java? I assume that because of _setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)_ . If so, why you want to `startActivityForResult` with also MainActivity ?

Comment: I am getting "Debugger is no longer active" and nothing else. I am getting the allow permission dialog but I am not getting the permission tag nor is my OnRequestPermissionsResult() called.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're not really running any UI code. For instance, I'd change what you have after granting permissions in the onRequestPermissionsResult() method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

To any UI you want to render.